# How to know which all tables have the column ex PHONE?

Tags: db2, mainframe, toad, db2-connect

Please advise.

In Db2 database how can I know the list of tables that contain the column ex PHONE?

Thanks,
Srihari

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried looking at the system catalog?

```
   SELECT CREATOR, TBNAME
   FROM   SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS
   WHERE  NAME = 'PHONE'
```